# Kendo optionLabel for drop down not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

```
Below is the kendo code for drop down control.
```

I am trying to display "Please select" option .This exact code works for all drop downs except this one.
option displays as part of the drop down list but not when the drop down loads first., Please help as i also tried closing and opening Visual studio and deleting history in browser too.

```
        function getRC(rcid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ddRCpicklist.length; i++) {
        if (ddRCpicklist[i].rcID === rcid) {
            return ddRCpicklist[i].RootCause;
        }
    }
    return 'No value matched';
}

function RootCauseDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    if (options.model.Name !== null) {
      var ddRC=  $('<input id="ddRootCause" required data-text-field="RootCause" data-value-field="rcID"  data-change="ddRootCauseSelect" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            index:0,
                            autoBind: false,
                            dataSource: { data: ddRCpicklist },
                            optionLabel: "--Please Select--"
                        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
                    }
     }

function ddRootCauseSelect(e) {
    ddValRootCause = $("#ddRootCause").val();
    alert(ddValRootCause);
}
```

Comment: @Mila how is it looking, any luck with resolving your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The `optionLabel` json data must be in the same format as the rest of your data that loads into your drop down.  So for you it should be:

```
optionLabel: { RootCause: '-- Please Select --', rcID: '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this unique behaviour refers to so called custom editors. Is your dropdown on the a grid by any chance ? Basically the code you are looking at is injecting dropdown control into a container in a grid for example (`.appendTo(container)`) and it will add your optionValue to the dropdown, but it will also select value which is shown on the grid. Let's say your drop down options are A,B,C and -select-, if the grid shows B in the column, the drop down will show B. If you not on the grid, the selected value is passed via option.

Remove following attribute and see what happens :

```
data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"
```